# Using ranges as keys in Ruby

Tags: ruby, range

I have a hash table that uses ranges as keys.

```
hash = {
  1..10 => "Foo",
  11..20 => "Bar",
  21..30 => "Baz",
  31..40 => "Quux",
}

 hash.find {|key, value| key == 5} # => `nil`
```

Why doesn't it return `Foo`?

EDIT:

As pointed out below, changed `Hash` to `hash`

Comment: Because `5` is not among the keys, of course :) It *matches* `1..10`, but it **is not** `1..10`.

Comment: Also use `hash =`. Or you will get `warning: already initialized constant Hash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `==` you check for a real equality and 5 is no range. But you may use `===` or `include?`. You may also try `select` instead `find`.

Example:

```
hash = {
  1..10 => "Foo",
  11..20 => "Bar",
  21..30 => "Baz",
  31..40 => "Quux",
}

p hash.find {|key, value| key === 5}       #[1..10, "Foo"]
p hash.find {|key, value| key.include?(5)} #[1..10, "Foo"]
p hash.select{|key, value| key === 5}      #{1..10=>"Foo"}
p hash.select{|key, value| key.include?(5)}#{1..10=>"Foo"}
```

Please see the different results. `find` returns an array, `select a Hash.

A closing remark: You used `Hash = ...`. I hope this a a typo and you wanted to use `hash`.

Comment: I find the `include?` method to be far clearer than the use of `===`, which is particularly confusing given that `===` is for stricter equality in some languages.

Answer (score 2):

`case when` constructions are designed to do this.

```
x = 5
p case x
  when 1..10  then "Foo"
  when 11..20 then "Bar"
  when 21..30 then "Baz"
  when 31..40 then "Quux"
end

# => "Foo"
```

Comment: Readers: being a case statement, `when 11..20` is determined by `(11..20) === 7`. [Range#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) is the same as [Range#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F), which, if the elements of the range are numeric, is the same as [Range#cover?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F).

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, you could use

```
Hash[(k-1)/10]
```

For example, if `k = 15`:

```
Hash[(15-1)/10] => Hash[1] => "Bar"
```

For the general case, if speed is important, first construct another hash:

```
H=Hash.flat_map { |r,v| r.to_a.product([v]) }.to_h
  #=> { 1=>"Foo" ,  2=>"Foo" ,..., 10=>"Foo",
  #    11=>"Bar" , 12=>"Bar" ,..., 20=>"Bar",
  #    ...
  #    31=>"Quux", 32=>"Quux",..., 40=>"Quux"}
```

so you can then just lookup values:

```
H[15] #=> "Bar"
H[35] #=> "Quux"
```